# CONSTRAINT to foreign keys to one table - causes error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am starting to build something like system up to the just cooperate with suggestions coming into the database called `ForslagOpslag`.

Every time I try to update table with likes, you will see it with this one error:

> Update cannot proceed due to validation errors. Please correct the following errors and try again.
>
> SQL71516 :: The referenced table '[dbo].[ForslagOpslag]' contains no
>   primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in
>   the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it
>   should be persisted.

Here is how I built my `ForslagOpslagLikes` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ForslagOpslagLikes] 
(
    [fk_brugerid] INT      NOT NULL,
    [opretdato]   DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [getid]       INT      NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ForslagOpslagLikes] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([fk_brugerid], [getid]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ForslagOpslagLikes_ToGetid] 
       FOREIGN KEY ([getid]) 
       REFERENCES [dbo].[ForslagOpslag]([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ForslagOpslagLikes_ToForslagBrugerid] 
       FOREIGN KEY ([fk_brugerid]) 
       REFERENCES [dbo].[ForslagOpslag]([fk_brugerid])
);
```

Reason I have both `fk_brugerid` and `getid` is for sure me that the user can not vote / like more once!

The way I have built my `ForslagOpslag` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ForslagOpslag] 
(
     [Id]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
     [text]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
     [fk_brugerid] INT            NOT NULL,
     [opretdato]   DATETIME       NOT NULL,

     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

like this to be my like system do:

```
ForslagOpslagLikes -> fk_brugerid to ForslagOpslag -> fk_brugerid

ForslagOpslagLikes -> getid to ForslagOpslag -> id
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You sound scandinavian, and Bruger means User (for all the non-scandinavians here).

What you appear to want is a `Bruger` (User) table, where `fk_brugerid` in `ForslagOpslag` is the user who created the record with `opretdato` being the creation date, and `ForslagOpslagLikes` is an association table of users who likes the ForslagOpslag with `opretdato` being the date they clicked on "Like".

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bruger] 
(
    [brugerid]    INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    ...,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Bruger]
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([brugerid])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ForslagOpslag] 
(
    [Id]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [text]        NVARCHAR(MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [fk_brugerid] INT            NOT NULL,
    [opretdato]   DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ForslagOpslag]
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ForslagOpslag_Bruger] 
       FOREIGN KEY ([fk_brugerid]) 
       REFERENCES [dbo].[Bruger] ([brugerid])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ForslagOpslagLikes] 
(
    [fk_brugerid] INT      NOT NULL,
    [opretdato]   DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [getid]       INT      NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ForslagOpslagLikes] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([fk_brugerid], [getid]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ForslagOpslagLikes_Bruger] 
       FOREIGN KEY ([fk_brugerid]) 
       REFERENCES [dbo].[Bruger] ([brugerid]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ForslagOpslagLikes_ForslagOpslag] 
       FOREIGN KEY ([getid]) 
       REFERENCES [dbo].[ForslagOpslag]([Id])
);
```

Comment: NIce! and thanks for the help .. Now it seems like I want / think, however, I have quite a bit about the quote with users as I have called it something else.

Answer (score 1):

Well - the error seems pretty clear: you're trying to estabslish a foreign key relationship to `ForslagOpslag.fk_brugerid` here:

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_ForslagOpslagLikes_ToForslagBrugerid] 
   FOREIGN KEY ([fk_brugerid]) 
   REFERENCES [dbo].[ForslagOpslag]([fk_brugerid])
```

but that column **is NOT** the primary key of that other table - and it's not a `UNIQUE` constraint either - so you **cannot** reference that column in a foreign key relationship.

But the column(s) that a foreign key references **must be** the primary key of that other table - or in SQL Server, it's good enough if there's a `UNIQUE` constraint on that column. You **must ensure** that the values you reference in `FroslagOpslag` only match a single column in that table - otherwise, you cannot establish a foreign key relationship

Comment: So you tell me it's over in `forslagopslag` should fk_brugerid and id be set for example like this: `primary key (Id, fk_brugerid)`

Comment: Well, either `fk_brugerid` needs to be the primary key, or you must be able to put a unique constraint on it. If you choose to create a **compound** primary key `(id, fk_brugerid)`, then you must have a single foreign key that references **both** columns, too.

Comment: It just will not do it the way you proposed to me, it will still continue to make mistakes. :(

Comment: After taking the code as you have proposed me and set into the `forslagopslag` comes this one mistake.

Update cannot proceed due to validation errors.  
Please correct the following errors and try again.

SQL71560 :: Table [dbo].[ForslagOpslag] does not have a clustered index.  Clustered indexes are required for inserting data in this version of SQL Server.
SQL71516 :: The referenced table '[dbo].[ForslagOpslag]' contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it should be persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the foreing key in your first table like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ForslagOpslagLikes] 
(
[fk_brugerid] INT      NOT NULL,
[opretdato]   DATETIME NOT NULL,
[getid]       INT      NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_ForslagOpslagLikes] 
   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([fk_brugerid], [getid]), 
CONSTRAINT [FK_ForslagOpslagLikes_ToGetid] 
   FOREIGN KEY ([getid]) 
   REFERENCES [dbo].[ForslagOpslag]([Id]),
);
```

Then you need to add the foreign key in the second table with the primary key with the first table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ForslagOpslag] 
(
 [Id]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
 [text]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
 [fk_brugerid] INT            NOT NULL,
 [opretdato]   DATETIME       NOT NULL,

 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
 CONSTRAINT [FK_ForslagOpslagLikes_ToForslagBrugerid] 
   FOREIGN KEY ([fk_brugerid]) 
   REFERENCES [dbo].[ForslagOpslagLikes]([fk_brugerid])
);
```